# Can you find any security threat available on this javascript problem?

Tags: javascript

let's say I have a code as a following:

```
object[hash].init();
```

Please assume that **hash** comes from the website hash (www.example.com#**hash**).

Is there any possible security holes in the code I displayed above? For instance, is it possible that I could put any code in the #**hash** that injects and trigger any malicious code?

Thanks.

Comment: object['alert("Malicious code..?");'] = 'No, just an object key.';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be no problem, `hash` will **not** be evaluated as JavaScript code, it will be treated as a string. In case the value of `hash` is not a valid property name for `object`, `object[hash]` will return `undefined` and you will get an error (not being able to call `init` on `undefined`).

On the other hand, if you use `hash` in a way where strings are evaluated as JavaScript code, *then* you have a security problem.

So this is fine:

```
object[hash].init();
```

but this is **not** (even with inner quotes):

```
setTimeout("object['" + hash + "'].init();", 100);
```

For example if `hash` was a string containing

```
']; alert('foo'); object['something
```

Then `alert('foo');` would be executed. It would be possible to inject and execute code without breaking your code.

---

That said, I would still not do it this way. It ties the code too much together. I would probable create a map of functions (which is similar to your example, but not the same):

```
var hashCodes = {
    'someHash': function() {
        object.something.init();
    }
};

if(hashCodes.hasOwnProperty(hash)) {
    hashCodes[hash]();
}
```

Comment: but he injects the string, which **could** contain javascript!

Comment: Any string **could** contain javascript. Or it could contain Fortran or Haskell code. It's not a security concern to _handle_ a string that may contain code; only _evaluating_ strings from untrusted sources is unsafe.

Comment: well yay, my thinking process was a little off, got my -2 ;)

Comment: There could be unexpected results if the hash is a 'magic' property like `__proto__`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation! yes in my real work I used mapping, it's for my object factory, even though your function mapping is logically safer (thx again).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a security thing, more of a design thing but accessing what may be internal data structures from a publicly-exposed URL may enable malicious users to manipulate your code in unexpected ways. While this won't directly expose a security flaw, unexpected code behaviour can make it easier for risks to sneak into the code. However, if you're sure that calling the init() methods in the 'wrong' order would be fine if it were to happen, then there's no problem.

Comment: Thx for the opinion, it's a relieve it turns into a design matter ;). This init() is some sort of a polymorphism that the objects must have. I put it in my example cause I'm not directly loading the chosen object, but directly execute a general function the object must have (which is the init()).

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could ever cause problems is if you used ES6 harmony proxies.

Proxies allow you to catch all methods. See the [FF Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```
var object = Proxy({
  "get": function _get(obj, name) {
    // name is an evil string containing javascript
    eval(name); // security risk
    return {
      "init": function _init() {
        // init code
      }
    };
  }
});
```

There is no other way to implement a catch-all. This particular catch-all evals the `name`

Comment: @kapep but you can't get access to the name. You need a proxy to access the name if the only line of code with the name is `object[name].init()`